# get the values of nested object/array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I get all the values in an array of this nested object:

```
{
    "report": {
        "firstSection": {
            "totalIncome": 9650000,
            "category": null,
            "mustPay": null,
            "tax": null,
            "bef": null,
            "message": "Los ingresos exceden el monto máximo para la modalidad monotributo"
        },
        "secondSection": {
            "subTotals": {
                "intTotal": 6295.166666666666,
                "ordTotal": 3884679.201041667
            },
            "unitaryProductionCost": 247.55291005291008,
            "unitaryInfo": {
                "unitarySalesCost": 16338.425925925927,
                "unitarySalesPrice": 23536.585365853658
            },
            "bankDebts": 0,
            "monthlySimpleDepreciation": 173333.33333333334
        },
    }
};
```

Basically I want an array like this, only with the values:

```
{
    "report": [
        9650000,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Los ingresos exceden el monto máximo para la modalidad monotributo",
        6295.166666666666,
        3884679.201041667,
        247.55291005291008,
        16338.425925925927,
        23536.585365853658,
        0,
        173333.33333333334,
    ]
}
```

I have this repl.it if it helps https://repl.it/@lizparody/UnlinedCruelResearch Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This recursive method, uses [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the current object's values. Values are iterated with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). If the value is an object (and not `null`), it's iterated with the method as well. The actual values are combined to a single array with [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const obj = {"report":{"firstSection":{"totalIncome":9650000,"category":null,"mustPay":null,"tax":null,"bef":null,"message":"Los ingresos exceden el monto máximo para la modalidad monotributo"},"secondSection":{"subTotals":{"intTotal":6295.166666666666,"ordTotal":3884679.201041667},"unitaryProductionCost":247.55291005291008,"unitaryInfo":{"unitarySalesCost":16338.425925925927,"unitarySalesPrice":23536.585365853658},"bankDebts":0,"monthlySimpleDepreciation":173333.33333333334}}};

const getObjectValues = (obj) => 
  Object.values(obj).reduce((r, v) => 
    r.concat(v && typeof v === 'object' ? getObjectValues(v) : v)
  , []);
  
const result = getObjectValues(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `const result = {"reports": getObjectValues(obj)};` will get the `result` in desired format

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code

```js
var data = {
    "report": {
        "firstSection": {
            "totalIncome": 9650000,
            "category": null,
            "mustPay": null,
            "tax": null,
            "bef": null,
            "message": "Los ingresos exceden el monto máximo para la modalidad monotributo"
        },
        "secondSection": {
            "subTotals": {
                "intTotal": 6295.166666666666,
                "ordTotal": 3884679.201041667
            },
            "unitaryProductionCost": 247.55291005291008,
            "unitaryInfo": {
                "unitarySalesCost": 16338.425925925927,
                "unitarySalesPrice": 23536.585365853658
            },
            "bankDebts": 0,
            "monthlySimpleDepreciation": 173333.33333333334
        },
    }
};

var ret = {"reports":[]}
function getleafs(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
     if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            getleafs(obj[key]);   
        } else {
            ret["reports"].push(obj[key]);   
        }
    }
}

getleafs(data);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trace object by recursive function:

```js
var obj = {
    "report": {
        "firstSection": {
            "totalIncome": 9650000,
            "category": null,
            "mustPay": null,
            "tax": null,
            "bef": null,
            "message": "Los ingresos exceden el monto máximo para la modalidad monotributo"
        },
        "secondSection": {
            "subTotals": {
                "intTotal": 6295.166666666666,
                "ordTotal": 3884679.201041667
            },
            "unitaryProductionCost": 247.55291005291008,
            "unitaryInfo": {
                "unitarySalesCost": 16338.425925925927,
                "unitarySalesPrice": 23536.585365853658
            },
            "bankDebts": 0,
            "monthlySimpleDepreciation": 173333.33333333334
        },
    }
};

function tracer(obj, arr)
{
    if ( typeof obj === 'object' )
    {
     for( key in obj)
        {
            if ( obj[key] == null )
            {
             arr.push(obj[key]);
            }
            else if ( typeof obj[key] === 'object' )
            {
             arr = tracer(obj[key],arr);
            }
            else
            {
             arr.push(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
 return arr;
}
var report = {report:[]};
report["report"] = tracer(obj, []);


console.log(report);
```

Comment: You're missing the `null` values because `typeof null === "object"; // true`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thank you, you are right, I have fixed it in my answer.